# Regular expression to move numbers from the start of a string to the end

Tags: regex, string

I am new to regular expressions and I'm wondering what expression I would use to move some numbers from the start of a string to the end, i.e. I would like to transform this:

'01 some text here of varying length'

to this:

'some text here of varying length 01'

The numbers are always two digits long, if this makes any difference.

Could someone help with this?

Comment: This is quite basic actually. And what is the tool that you are using?

Comment: What language are you using? It can make quite the difference

Comment: Why use regex? Looks like simple string manipulation so there are most likely much more efficent ways to accomplish this.

Comment: If it is always two digits, and always at the start of the string, you don't need a regular expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

search pattern: `^(\d{2})\s*(.+)`

replace pattern: `$2 $1`

for random count of digits search pattern will be `^(\d+)\s*(.+)`

Comment: You still don't know what language he's using. Nor did he say that there must be a space after the digits. It's good getting answers in early, but only if they answer the question specifically.

Comment: @LeonardChallis I agree, but the most difference will be only in surrounding of patterns.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same with the `REGEXREPLACE` function provided in Google Spreadsheets? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245

I have tried `=REGEXREPLACE("02 test string","^(\d{2})","\s*(.+)")` with no success. It seems it just doesnt support regex substitution, is that true?

Comment: @PaulH I never worked with Google Spreadsheets, but you seem to use wrong substitution anyway (I think it will result in "\s*(.+) test string" for your case). Try something like =REGEXREPLACE("02 aaa", "^(\d{2})\s*(.+)", "$2 $1").

Answer (score 2):

In Regex:

- Start of line is ^
- Numbers can be denoted as [0-9] or as \d
- . represents any character
- Repetitions can be expressed with *
- Patterns can be captured using ()
- Capture groups are names as $1, $2 ... $n

So to sum up, the following pattern should match your string.

```
^(\d\d) (.*)
```

In the example above, I have captured the numbers in $1 and rest of the string in $2; so now the desired output can be achieved by swapping them, like so:

```
$2 $1
```

Comment: You've forgotten space between `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov - I don't think so, $2 will contain the space as well.  . can match <space>

Comment: Yes, but after replacement it will be in the start of the string, and we need to move it before digits.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov : Thanks, I have corrected the answer now.